# C# : datagridview value to textbox on form load

Tags: c#, events, datagridview, constructor, rows

i have `datagridview` it goes like this

[image]

the arrow select the first row. and i want to make that first row in to `textbox` automatically . like the following picture

[image]

i use `datagridview.cellClick` event to make the second picture works

however, i need to make it work on constructor ( when the form started, the three texboxt already filled with `1` `jodi` `081234125125`), without using `datagridview.cellclick` event

how do i do that ?

when i use the following code

```
 textBox1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["nomor_nasabah"].Value.ToString();
```

it shows
[image]

Comment: By including in the Form_Load event method the same code that you include in the cellClick one?

Comment: i'm going to put the code into my constructor. my constructor instead of Form_Load event

Comment: Why not in the form_load event? You have to let all the controls to be "created properly" before interacting with them; perhaps that's why you are getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one:

```
private void SetFirstRowSelected()
{
   if (dataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0)
   {
      var row = dataGridView1.Rows[0];

      textBox1.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
      //and so on

      dataGridView1.CurrentCell = row.Cells[0]; //set focus to first cell in first row
   }
}
```

and call it in your `Form_Load` event.

`var row = dataGridView1.Rows[0];` means that we are selecting the very first row from grid. `row` variable is the reference to it just to avoid typing `dataGridView1.Rows[0]` every time.

`dataGridView1.CurrentCell = row.Cells[0]` means that we are selecting the first cell in first row (it is the cell in "nomar_nasabah" column).

Comment: what is this line means ? `var row = dgv.Rows[0];`  and this one ` dgv.CurrentCell = row.Cells[0];` means ? what is the difference between `focus` , `currentRow` and `selectedRow` ?

Comment: yep it is clearer now, so that var row is just like shortcode for `datagridview1.rows `

Answer (score 0):

textBox1.Text=dataGridView1.SelectRow[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

textBox2.Text=dataGridView1.SelectRow[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();

textBox3.Text=dataGridView1.SelectRow[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();